# Delete all the map keys with zero values

Tags: c++, dictionary, erase

There is this map whose keys belong to the {0, 1, 2, 3}.

I need to erase all the keys whose value equals 0.

Is this code a good practice?

```
map<int, int> nums = {{0, 1}, {1, 3}, {2, 0}, {3, 1}};

for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    if (nums.count(i) > 0 && nums[i] == 0)
        nums.erase(i);
```

It seems to work but iterating over the map and erasing the key in the same loop makes me uncomfortable.

If this code is not a good fashion, what is the best way to erase all the keys with zero value in the map?

Comment: You are not iterating over a map, you are iterating over a range of numbers [0..4).

Comment: Are you trying to use a `std::multimap`? Otherwise you can only have one unique key of 0.

Comment: Maybe add the keys you want to delete in a list and then delete them at a second moment

Comment: Do you mean that you want to remove all the key value pairs that have a value of 0 (key could be anything)?

Comment: @JustinRandall yes, I do.

Comment: @JustinRandall `std::multimap` does not have `operator[]`

Comment: You are doing 3 lookups per key in the worst case, while you should do none, wow.

Comment: @Slava whoops that's right thank you for the correction.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is a good example very close to your task http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/erase
I updated it for you.

```
#include <map>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::map<int, int> c = {{1, 1}, {2, 0}, {3, 3},
                                    {4, 0}, {5, 5}, {6, 0}};
    // erase all key-value pairs with zero values from c
    for(auto it = c.begin(); it != c.end(); )
        if(it->second == 0)
            it = c.erase(it);
        else
            ++it;
    for(auto& p : c)
        std::cout << p.second << ' ';
}
```

Output:

```
1 3 5
```

I recommend you to visit http://en.cppreference.com more often.

Comment: For small number of elements like in OP it would not matter, but this solution is potentially way faster than the original one.

Comment: @BaummitAugen yea 3 lookups vs none, difference could be significant.